# RegExp to match hashtag at the begining of the string or after a space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have looked through previous questions and answers, however they do not solve the following:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#notHashTag
```

The closest I got to is this: `(^#|(?:\s)#)(\w+)`, which finds the hashtag in half the necessary cases and also includes the leading space in the returned text. Here are all the cases that need to be matched:

```
#hashtag
a #hashtag
a #hashtag world
cool.#hashtag
##hashtag, but only until the comma and starting at second hash
#hashtag#hashtag two separate matches
```

And these should be skipped:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#notHashTag
Word#notHashTag
#ab is too short to be a hashtag, 3 characters minimum
```

Comment: Have you seen RegExp 101? Really nice for live testing of RegExp, perhaps with some fiddling you can nail it! - http://regex101.com

Comment: @ToddMotto spent almost an hour at RegExPal with no luck.

Comment: `cool.#hashtag` why this is a hashtag?

Comment: What's the difference between `cool.#hashtag` and `Punctuation .#hashtag`? Does the space need to affect this?

Comment: @KendallFrey actually I thought about it and decided to let the ` .#*` be a valid hastag as well. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for everything but `#hashtag#duplicates`, and because JS doesn't support lookbehind, that's probably not possible to match that by itself.

```
\B#\w{3,}
```

`\B` is designed to match only between two word characters or two non-word characters. Since `#` is a non-word character, this forces the match to be preceded by a space or punctuation, or the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(?:^|[\s.])(#+\w{3,})(#+\w{3,})?
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/kG1nD5